# In ggplot, how to create a simple x-axis/number line with values

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a very basic question, but unfortunately I could not find a solution so far.

For data such as:

```r
library(tibble)

my_df <-
  tribble(~manufacturer, ~mpg,
          "audi", 17.6,
          "lincoln", 11.3,
          "nissan", 18.1)

## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   manufacturer   mpg
##   <chr>        <dbl>
## 1 audi          17.6
## 2 lincoln       11.3
## 3 nissan        18.1
```

If I define a scale range of `c(0, 30)`, how can I produce a `ggplot` visualization that shows a horizontal axis only?

A demonstration of the desired output would be (ugly and not drawn to scale):
[image: my_ugly_scale]

- No y-axis
- No background color (just white or transparent)

---

This is so basic that it's embarrassing to post. But actually I don't have a clue. Even not which `geom` to work with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092220/plot-only-y-axis-but-nothing-else

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54150497/9689554 here with ggplot2

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed those.... I'll see if I can use them to work out my problem. Will report back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another try:

```
ggplot(my_df, aes(x=mpg, y=0)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(shape = 108, size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=manufacturer),hjust=0.5, vjust=-2)+
  geom_text(aes(label=mpg),hjust=.5, vjust=2) +
  theme_void()
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to add the scale limits (`0` and `30`) using the following: **step 1 --** I added two rows to `my_df`: `my_df %>% add_row(manufacturer = c("min", "max"), mpg = c(0, 30)) %>% ggplot(...)`. **step 2 --** I removed the labels "min" and "max" using `geom_text(aes(label = stringr::str_remove_all(manufacturer, paste(c("min", "max"), collapse = "|"))), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -2) +`. Lovely :)

Comment: @Emman If that is the answer to your question please consider accepting it as  the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will need some refinement by may be a good place to start

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

my_df <- data.frame(manu = c("audi", "lincoln", "nissan"),
                    mpg = c(17.6, 11.3, 18.1))
ggplot(my_df) +
  geom_linerange(aes(y = 1, xmin = 0, xmax = 30)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = 0, ymin = .8, ymax = 1.2)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = 30, ymin = .8, ymax = 1.2)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = mpg, y = 1.2, label = manu)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = mpg, y = .9, label = mpg)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = mpg), ymin = .95, ymax = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,2)) +
  theme_void()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
my_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, y=0)) + 
   ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(y=0.15,label=manufacturer)) +
   geom_segment(aes(xend=mpg, yend=0.05)) +
   coord_fixed(ratio =10) +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,30), expand = c(0,0)) + 
   theme_minimal() +
   theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.y  = element_blank(),
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         panel.grid = element_blank(),
         axis.line.x = element_line(color=1))
```

[image]